# Ember.js ajax POST request not going through mirage

Tags: javascript, ajax, ember.js, mirage

I am writing some tests for a component in my Ember application, where the component performs an ajax POST request to my servers API that will return a string of the location of a file.

I have added in the `mirage/config.js` file a route that should be used when the ajax request is performed.

```
  this.post('/foobar', () => {
    return "test";
  });
```

When I run my tests, I can see in the network tab and console that the ajax request is attempting to be performed on my localhost, but is getting a Connection Refused error.

`POST http://localhost:8000/foobar net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`.

When putting a debugger in the `mirage/config.js` file, it is not stopping there and it seems to be ignoring the route in my `mirage/config.js` entirely.

The URL and namespace are all set up in the config file.

When I run my app on localhost and hit this endpoint, it correctly goes through Mirage. But it doesn't use mirage during testing.

The code that is making the ajax request.

```
ajax.request(
        uri.toString(),
        {
          headers: ajax.get('headers'),
          method: 'POST',
          data: data
        });
```

This is done on a button click, which I am "clicking" from my integration test.

What can I do to test further and find out why the request is not going through mirage?

Comment: Can you share the code that’s triggering the request?

Comment: Definitely! I will add it to the description above. @BuckDoyle

Comment: Does the test have a call to `setupMirage`?

Comment: @BuckDoyle It did, but it was having issues and not working correctly. I was able to fix it but adding a `startMirage` call. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the issue was in the way that I was starting mirage in my integration test.

https://www.ember-cli-mirage.com/versions/v0.4.x/manually-starting-mirage/

Following these steps I was able to properly init mirage and get my tests working.

Comment: .@Childishforlife you should accept your own answer if it worked for you

Comment: @JulienPalmas It keeps saying I can accept my own answer for 1 hour?